# can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform

Tags: java, ubuntu

I was hoping to run PHPStorm on my raspberry pi running Ubuntu Mate. I managed to install Java 8 but get the following errors when trying to run PHPStorm:

```
./inspect.sh 
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library yjpagent-linux on the library path, with error: libyjpagent-linux.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
```

Is there any way round this IA 32-bit dependency or does anyone have any mnore information on this limitation?

Comment: If that ships with PHPStorm (try `find . -name "libyjpagent-linux.so"` in the package directory) then you are out of luck unless the source is available.  I notice there's a [github page](https://github.com/simplegeo/yjpagent) for it, but the repo contains only compiled binaries, which is not a good sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by replacing the the libyjpagent-linux.so with the ARM7 version from https://www.yourkit.com/download/yjp-2015-build-15064-linux.tar.bz2

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IA stands for intel architecture and IA_32 libs is a library to run 32 bit programs on a 64 bit architectures (successor of 32 bit architectures in a broad sense). Since ARM is based on completely different architecture, you can't make use of IA_32.so in this case. One (and probably only) of the option is to compile library source on arm platform and generate shared object your self for your platform (in this case ARM) but like goldilocks suggested, this particular library doesn't have its source available on github or anywhere else.

Hope it helps.

Update :

Looks like there is source available on profiler's official site. Here is a link. https://www.yourkit.com/download/yjp-2015-build-15064-linux.tar.bz2

Comment: Thanks. it seems to be some kind of profiler and there is an ARM version it seems https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/agent.jsp

Comment: Also https://www.yourkit.com/download/ so maybe I can find a compiled version in there.

Comment: @codecowboy You're right. There's source available. Here is a link. https://www.yourkit.com/download/yjp-2015-build-15064-linux.tar.bz2 Untar, compile and install it as per instructions given in package's readme file. Should work fine.

Comment: Just tried it and it works :)

Comment: @codecowboy Cool. You may like to up vote an answer which took time to help you. :)

Comment: No problem. You may like to upvote the question which ended up costing me 50 bounty points :(

Comment: Haha. Done. :-)